# How to make a specular child copy on an object

Tags: parent

Let's make it clear, I need to create a specular copy of my object which gets modified if I edit the original one.
How can i do this?

Comment: Can you explain better? Do you need to have in the same file blend, 2 copies of the sam mesh?

Comment: make 2 separate objects in the same scene which are linked,I mean, if I edit the first one, the second one gets modified too.
furthermore if I can get them to be specular, it would be even better.

Comment: by specular you mean a mirror  like this https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html?highlight=mirror%20modifier#mirror-modifier?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean make it specular? Blender can create object instances which have linked mesh data, I.E. changes in one are automatically reflected in the other. Just copy the object with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to clone it

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a global specularity value regardless of material?

Such as:

[image]